# MySQL use generated column in select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query that runs a brief operation (totalling the counts in a select statement) and I want to use the result to do a math operation, but I'm getting an error.

Table:

```
id  |   group   |   count   |
-----------------------------
1       1           3
2       1           2
```

Query:

```
select id, count,
  (select sum(count) from table group by group) as total,
  count/total as percent 
from table
```

The error is because there is no real "total" column in the table. How can I make the query work?

Comment: You're not giving any error message.

Comment: Sorry about that! I thought I described it with the last paragraph, but officially the error is `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'total' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can save `total` as a [variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html), then use that in the division calculation.

```
SELECT 
  `id`, `count`, 
   @total:=(SELECT sum(`count`) FROM `table` GROUP BY `group`) AS `total`, 
  `count`/@total AS `percent` 
FROM `table`
```

NOTE: `GROUP` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL.  You *should* enclose it (and all other field/table names) in backticks (`).

Comment: BOOM, we have a winner! Thank you, Rocket.

Comment: The MySQL documentation warns against doing this. 
"As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.... you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed."  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Comment: PaulC is correct. The order of execution is undefined. E.g. If `percent` evaluates first, you will be using the previous row's `@total`.

Answer (score 15):

You can also do this without introducing a variable:

```
select id, 
   count, 
   (select sum(count) from `table` group by `group`) as total, 
   (select count/total) as percent 
from `table`;
```

Produces:

```
+------+-------+-------+---------+
| id   | count | total | percent |
+------+-------+-------+---------+
|    1 |     3 |     5 |  0.6000 |
|    2 |     2 |     5 |  0.4000 |
+------+-------+-------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Comment: Simple and clean solution

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the inner query needs to generate 1 result per row, not 1 for every group. You want to add a where clause in the inner query saying something like

`where inner_table.group = outer_table.group`

so that only one result is returned.

Answer (score 0):

`group` is a reserved word in mysql, as is `table`, you should use it like:

```
select id, count, (select sum(count) from `table` group by `group`) as total, count/total as percent from `table`
```

For more information: [MySQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

You'll see there that you can actually use `count` but I would put all table and column names in quotes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an answer for MySql but by mistake if anyone lands here for MSSql as i did, it is as simple as below for MSSql

```
select id, count,
  total = (select sum(count) from table group by group),
  count/total as percent 
from table
```