# MYSQL: Using math in SELECT with alias

Tags: mysql

I have an extremely complex SQL query that I am needing help with. Essentially, this query will see how many total assignments a student is assigned (`total`) and how many they have completed (`completed`) for the course. I need one final column that would give me the percentage of completed assignments, because I want to run a query to select all users who have completed less than 50% of their assignments.

1. What am I doing wrong? I am getting an error "Unknown column 'completed' in 'field list'"
2. Is there a better way to execute this? I am open to changing my query.

Query:

```
SELECT students.usid AS ID, students.firstName, students.lastName, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(workID) FROM assignGrades
    INNER JOIN students ON students.usid = assignGrades.usid
    INNER JOIN assignments ON assignments.assID = assignGrades.assID
    WHERE 
        assignGrades.usid = ID AND 
        assignments.subID = 4 AND
        (
            assignGrades.submitted IS NOT NULL OR 
            (assignGrades.score IS NOT NULL AND CASE WHEN assignments.points > 0 THEN assignGrades.score ELSE 1 END > 0)
        )
) AS completed,
(
    SELECT COUNT(workID) FROM assignGrades
    INNER JOIN students ON students.usid = assignGrades.usid
    INNER JOIN assignments ON assignments.assID = assignGrades.assID
    WHERE 
        assignGrades.usid = ID AND 
        assignments.subID = 4 AND
        (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 HOUR) > assignments.assigned
) AS total, 
(completed/total)*100 AS percentage
FROM students 
INNER JOIN profiles ON profiles.usid = students.usid 
INNER JOIN classes ON classes.ucid = profiles.ucid 
WHERE classes.utid=2 AND percentage < 50
```

If I cut the (`percentage`) part in the SELECT statement, the query runs as expected. See below for results.

[image]

Information about the tables involved in this query:

- assignGrades: Lists the student's score for each assignment.
- assignments: List the assignments for each course.
- students: Lists student information
- classes: Lists class information
- profiles: Links a student to a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to check when value is >50% but you don't need to see it, you might use a different approach using `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT (now) AS completed, (totalassignments) AS total
FROM db
HAVING (completed/total)*100 > 50;
```

Comment: I really like this! What about if I wanted to see the percentage? Any ideas there?

Comment: The issue is you are selecting something with an alias so, as far as I remember, those alias cannot be used for operations. If you had those data in a field you could have used for operations.
Found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681299/mysql-use-generated-column-in-select-query) where they are mentioning similar solutions. You can check and try both accepted answer and second one.